# Abline not showing up, only first two regression coefficients used

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I'm trying to perform a multivariable regression with the dataset MTCars:

```
car_data = read.csv("C:\\Users\\johan\\Documents\\Australien\\Exarbete\\MTCars.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)

## plot a x/y scatter plot with the data
plot(as.numeric(car_data$cyl) + as.numeric(car_data$disp) + as.numeric(car_data$hp) + as.numeric(car_data$drat) + as.numeric(car_data$wt) + as.numeric(car_data$qsec) + as.numeric(car_data$vs) + as.numeric(car_data$am) + as.numeric(car_data$gear) + as.numeric(car_data$carb), as.numeric(car_data$mpg), main = "Scatterplot")

## create a "linear model" = the regression
car_regression <- lm(as.numeric(car_data$mpg) ~ as.numeric(car_data$cyl) + as.numeric(car_data$disp) + as.numeric(car_data$hp) + as.numeric(car_data$drat) + as.numeric(car_data$wt) + as.numeric(car_data$qsec) + as.numeric(car_data$vs) + as.numeric(car_data$am) + as.numeric(car_data$gear) + as.numeric(car_data$carb))
## generate a summary of the regression
summary(car_regression)

## add the regression line to the scatterplot
abline(car_regression, col="blue")
```

I keep getting the error: "Warning message:
In abline(car_regression, col = "blue") :
only using the first two of 11 regression coefficients", and the regression line does not show up in the scatterplot either. I've tried converting the variables to numeric with as.numeric, and there are no missing values. How do I solve this?

Comment: Consider this reading: https://www.statology.org/plot-multiple-linear-regression-in-r/

Comment: The `+` inside a model formular has a very different meaning than elsewhere. I don't know what you believe your plot is showing but I doubt that you are actually intending to do what you are doing there. If indeed it is as intendended then it is not sensible. (All these `as.numeric` should not be necessary.)